# Google Analytics: Race condition during analytics.js initialization?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am using Google Analytics (analytics.js) to monitorize a site. I want to be able of reporting exceptions if any of the scripts fails to execute.

So for example if an application has a single .js file, if that file contains a typo I want to be able of report that exception to GA. So, I cannot put the "create" call inside my JS, I have to put it earlier.

I found a way that works 90% of the time by executing in the HEAD:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);

    // MY CODE
    i[r]('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    i.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        i[r]('send', 'exception', {
            'exDescription': "'" + e.message + "': '" + e.filename + "' at line " + e.lineno,
            'exFatal': true
        });
    });
    // END MY CODE

})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
```

When my application load reports two things, a "pageview" and after a "timing" (that always happens after the "pageview"), but around a 40% of the times, only the first one is reported to the GA server. Despite of the call to "window.ga" being done anyway, and no error on the console, I see the HTTP request for the "timing" missing. But again only happens a 30-40% of the time.

It looks like a race condition, so I tried to load the script synchronously by splitting the code in three blocks. First block inits the queue, second gets the file synchronously, and the third initializes the tracker:

```
<script>
((function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date()
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
</script>
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script>
 window.ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
 window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        window.ga('send', 'exception', {
            'exDescription': "'" + e.message + "': '" + e.filename + "' at line " + e.lineno,
            'exFatal': true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And it works every single time. However, if I set the script as `async` again:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async></script>
```

Then again around the 40% of the times it miss the timing event.

Why is this happening?

Which would be the right way of achieving my initial idea of reporting script parsing exceptions?

Comment: If it's async, it's not going to be on the same stack, and if the application started to run - and is a large application with mostly synchronous code- then it's possible an exception will occur before the current stack is cleared - meaning before a new stack is created with the analytics in the loop.

Comment: How are you sending your pageview and timing hits? You haven't shown that code.

Comment: It is standard as appear in the docs. There is no much options on that matter.

Comment: I only ask because what you have looks like it should work to me. Do you have a live page I could look at?

Comment: Nope. I will try to create one. It actually works, but fails sometimes.